# Application is undefined in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, asp.net-web-api

I am trying to create a AngularJS and WEB API application but this is my first time. I am getting following error...

```
0x800a1391 - JavaScript runtime error: 'MyApp' is undefined
```

My AngularJS Service file is like below and this is where it gives the error above...

```
MyApp.factory('CityService', ['$http', function ($http) {
   var urlBase = 'http://localhost:58057/api';
   var CityService = {};
   CityService.getCities = function () {
       return $http.get(urlBase + '/Cities');
   };
   return CityService;
}]);
```

Where should I define MyApp?

Comment: In your js file or declare in factory also.
declare var MyApp = angular.module('MyApp',[]);

Comment: have you defined any module in your app ?

Comment: there is a full tutorial on the Angular's official web site.

Comment: I didnt do anything about MODULE. I dont know what to do about MODULE. I better use Angular's official web site